# How to use whereIn to check multiple columns?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have this query:

```
$query->whereHas($key,function($q) use($option){
            $q->whereIn('district', $option);
            $q->whereIn('region', $option);
          });
```

But its not working. I want to check `district` and `region` and i get an array from `$option`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For `AND` use:

```
$query->whereHas($key,function($q) use($option){
        $q->whereIn('district', $option)
          ->whereIn('region', $option);
    });
```

For `OR`:

```
$query->whereHas($key,function($q) use($option){
        $q->whereIn('district', $option)
          ->orWhereIn('region', $option);
    });
```